# Loop is not resetting?

Tags: java, loops

Belowe is code that checks for matching parentheses to see if they are nested properly. It seems really simple, but I don't understand why `i` does not reset to 0 once a nested match is found. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
    String testString = "{}()[] ";
    char [] openParenthesis = {'(','{','['};
    char [] closeParenthesis = {')','}',']'};

    ArrayList<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : testString.toCharArray())
    {
        characterList.add(c);
        System.out.println("This is what is added to the list Arraylist: " + c);
    }

    System.out.println();


for(int i = 0; i < characterList.size()-1; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("1st Loop: " +characterList.get(i));
                System.out.println("1st Loop: " + characterList.get(i + 1));
                System.out.println("1st Loop: " + i);
                System.out.println();

                for(int j = 0; j < openParenthesis.length; j++)
                {
                    if (characterList.get(i) == openParenthesis[j])
                    {
                        if(characterList.get(i + 1) == closeParenthesis[j])
                        {
                            System.out.println("Nested Match");
                            System.out.println(characterList.get(i));
                            System.out.println(characterList.get(i + 1));
                            System.out.println();
                            characterList.remove(i);
                            characterList.remove(i + 1);
                            i = 0;
                        }
                    }   
                }
        }
```

Comment: Where are the declarations of charaterList and openParenthesis? What are their types?

Comment: sorry just added them

Comment: Wouldnt the `i++` increment come after the `i=0` call (in the if block)? So the first time it would be 0 but everytime after that it would start at 1?

Comment: I dont think so but you could be right.

Comment: @Calgar99 can you post the testString's content? and what you expect?

Comment: added. I was hoping that the loop would repeat from the beginning and that by then the charcterlist would be empty

Comment: Just for the record, I'm used to seeing people use stacks when they write a program to see if parentheses are nested properly.

Comment: @Howercraft Full of Eeels, I apologise it was slip on the keyboard

Comment: I must have accidently clicked undo. I didnt see any pop-up to undo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all you are removing the wrong spots in the ArrayList.

Because it is an ArrayList `characterList.remove(i);` will move everything over to the left one spot, so then the next like `characterList.remove(i+1);` removes the one to the right of where you want.

You also need to add a break in the openParenthesis loop so you can start the search over at the beginning of the array if you find a match.

You also need to change the `i = 0` to `i = -1` because it increments it to one BEFORE it starts the next iteration of the for loop.

Finally, you should be using `.equals()` instead of `==` because the ArrayList returns a `Character` object instead of a `char`.

Here is what I came up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < characterList.size() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("1st Loop: " + characterList.get(i));
        System.out.println("1st Loop: " + characterList.get(i + 1));
        System.out.println("1st Loop: " + i);
        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < openParenthesis.length; j++) {
            if (characterList.get(i).equals(openParenthesis[j])) {
                if (characterList.get(i + 1).equals(closeParenthesis[j])) {
                    System.out.println("Nested Match");
                    System.out.println(characterList.get(i));
                    System.out.println(characterList.get(i + 1));
                    System.out.println();
                    characterList.remove(i);
                    characterList.remove(i);
                    i = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code has fixed all the errors mentioned above and should run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what your `testString` is. I tested it with value `foo()` and loop did go inside `if(characterList.get(i + 1) == closeParenthesis[j])` condition.

However there is a problem in your code where you have:

```
characterList.remove(i);
characterList.remove(i + 1);
```

Which will result in **`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`** since `i+1` location has become invalid (out of range) after deleting `ith` element. It should be other way round:

```
characterList.remove(i + 1);
characterList.remove(i);
```

Also instead of `i=0;` you need to set it to: `i = -1;`

**And more importantly break out of inner for loop by calling break.**

So your code in the end should look like this:

```
i = -1;
break;
```

### See working demo: http://ideone.com/DfGJ2m

Answer (score 1):

Obviously because of the i++ in `for` loop `i` equal to `1`. if you really want to set `0` for `i` again. use `i=-1`;

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop increments `i` by one AFTER the body of the loop is completed.

Thus, you set `i=0`, you exit the body of the loop, `i++` is called, and you enter the loop body once more with `i ==1`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could have used a stack data structure and using a process similar to http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/

Answer (score 0):

When you store a character in a list, java autoboxes it to a Character.  You cannot use the == operator to compare two Characters for equality, but must use the .equals() method, as this code demonstrates:

```
  Character aOne = new Character('a');
  Character aTwo = new Character('a');

  if(aOne == aTwo)
  {
     System.out.println("aOne and aTwo == operator says they are equal");
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.println("aOne and aTwo == operator says they are NOT equal");
  }

  if(aOne.equals(aTwo))
  {
     System.out.println("aOne and aTwo .equals operator says they are equal");
  }
```

Code prints out:

```
aOne and aTwo == operator says they are NOT equal
aOne and aTwo .equals operator says they are equal
```